# How are these order statistics inequalities derived?

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, statistical-inference, order-statistics

> Let $\theta \lt x_{(1)} \lt x_{(n)} \lt \theta + 1$ be ordre
>    statistics for $X_1, \dots, X_n$ iid uniform random variables on
>    $(\theta, \theta + 1)$.
>
> Let $R = X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$ and $M = (X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}) / 2$.  Then
>    we have the inverse transformation  $X_{(1)} = (2M-R)/2$ and $X_{(n)}
>  = (2M + R) /2$.
>
> Then the joint pdf is $n(n-1)r^{n-2}$ if $0 \lt r \lt 1, \theta +
>  (r/2) \lt m \lt \theta + 2 - (r/2)$

How are the conditions $0 \lt r \lt 1, \theta + (r/2) \lt m \lt \theta + 2 - (r/2)$ derived?

I see how $0 \lt r \lt 1$ since the the $x_{(i)}$'s could be arbitrarily close together or $(\theta + 1) - \theta = 1$ apart, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to show the $m$ inequalities.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong inequality on the right. It should be $m<\theta+1-r/2.$ This can be checked to give a proper joint distribution as

$$\int_0^1\int _{\theta+\frac{r}{2}}^{\theta+1-\frac{r}{2}}n(n-1)r^{n-2}dm\, dr
=\int_0^1 n(n-1)r^{n-2}(1-r)=n(n-1)\left[\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right]=1.$$

$M=\dfrac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ and $R=X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$ implies $M-\dfrac{R}{2}=X_{(1)}> \theta,$ which gives you the inequality $\theta+r/2 < m.$

Similarly, $M+\dfrac{R}{2}=X_{(n)} < \theta+1,$ which means $m<\theta+1-r/2.$